# How to agg function according to condition?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'B01', 0],['john', 'C01', 0],['katty', 'A01', 0],['katty', 'B01', 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'orderID','buying_channel']) 

purchase_channel = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"buying_channel": sum((x.buying_channel)/(x.buying_channel.count()))}))

purchase_channel.head()
```

I want to calculate the person buying channel, '1' is a channel, '0' is another. (1 = online, 0 = offline)

Instead of calculating as a whole, which gives 0.6 as a result,
I want to calculate it based on the orderID.

Expected result:

```
data2 = [['john', 0.33], ['katty', 0]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['name','buying_channel'])
df2
```

Because 'john' buys 3 times, only one time buying online, the rest offline.
therefore, how to agg based on orderID?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say he buys 3 times, 1 online the rest offline, when out of his 5 rows, 3 of them are 1. What is the purpose of `orderID`?

Comment: orderID : A01, A01, A01
same orderID = 1 purchase,

meaning he buy 1 time in receipt A01 with 3 items

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop duplicates on `name, orderID` and average the value on `buying_channel`:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['name','orderID'])
   .groupby('name', as_index=False)
   .buying_channel.mean()
)
```

Output:

```
    name  buying_channel
0   john        0.333333
1  katty        0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edited based on OPs edit:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'A01', 1],['john', 'B01', 0],['john', 'C01', 0],['katty', 'A01', 0],['katty', 'B01', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'orderID','buying_channel']) 
df_1 = df.merge(df.groupby(['name','orderID'],as_index=False)['buying_channel'].sum(),on=['name','orderID'],how='left')
df_1['purchase_channel'] = df_1['buying_channel_x']/df_1['buying_channel_y']
df_1 = df_1.drop(['buying_channel_y'],axis=1).fillna(0).rename(columns={'buying_channel_x':'buying_channel'}).groupby('name')['purchase_channel'].max()
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
name
john     0.333333
katty    0.000000
Name: purchase_channel, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I had revised my question, have a look. In the end, I will groupby the name. Is there a way using lambda?

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to get can be reached with `.value_counts(normalize=True)`.

[Docs to value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

Hope this helps! If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify the question, as I find it a little confusing. That will also help others who might have better ideas to solve your problem.

EDIT1:

After the question edit, I think you could achieve it this way:

```py
df.groupby('name')['buying_channel'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)[1] if (x==1).sum() else 0)
```

which outputs:

```
name
john     0.6
katty    0.0
Name: buying_channel, dtype: float64
```

In the lambda, after the normalized `value_counts()`, I select the result for `1`, obtaining the proportion of times 1 was present for each name. The else clause avoids errors in case there were no `1`s for a given name, as happens with 'katty'.

If you want, you can then get a daaframe from that appending `.to_frame()` at the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my mistake, I had revised my question, have a look.

Comment: @Jonathan edited answer accordingly. Hope it now solves your issue!

Comment: for 'john', the answer should be 0.33

Comment: Not with the new df you posted. John had 5 entries, 3 of the had 1s. That's 0.6.

Comment: orderID : A01, A01, A01 same orderID = 1 purchase, meaning he buy 1 time in receipt A01 with 3 items

Comment: Well I got really lost now. He has 3 orderIDs. The only one made online has 1 in all cases; the rest is all 0. I don't understand what would give .33 as a result.

Comment: one orderID = one purchase, john have 3 orderID, which mean he buy 3 times. one time online, two time offline. therefore 1/3 = 0.33